# Is 'buggy_logger' a reference to the 'status' string in this Ruby example?

Tags: ruby, string, reference

In this example, do the nukes get launched because any changes that you make to buggy_logger get applied to the 'status' string - just like using a copy of a reference to an object -> when you make a change to the copy of the reference, the change gets applied to the underlying object -> that change is, in turn, reflected in any other references to the object. So, in other words, buggy_logger is an alias to the 'status' object without specifically using the alias keyword? Is that correct? So, in ruby, you just say

```
b = a
```

and then any changes you make to b afterwards are also reflected in a. Or is this only true because we're talking about Strings, which are mutable in Ruby?

```
# example-4.rb

status = "peace"

buggy_logger = status

print "Status: "
print buggy_logger << "\n" # <- This insertion is the bug.

def launch_nukes?(status)
  unless status == 'peace'
    return true
  else
    return false
  end 
end

print "Nukes Launched: #{launch_nukes?(status)}\n"

# => Status: peace
# => Nukes Launched: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is because strings are objects.  Try

```
buggy_logger = status.dup
```

If you want a distinct object with the same initial value.

As for your question about `alias` I suspect you aren't correctly understanding how  `alias` is used in ruby; it's used on methods, not objects, and isn't related to mutability.

Note also that the same semantics would have applied with any class; if status had been an array, a file, or anything else (provided it had mutable state suitable for use as a logger), you would have gotten analogous results.

One warning about `dup` though.  If your object refers to other objects, the copy will also refer to the *same* objects.  It's fine once you start thinking about it the right way, but tricky till then.

Comment: Oh, that's so cool -- I didn't know there was a dup method. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok. So it's not just strings. Thanks again.